# Cannot find module 'supertest'

Tags: typescript, node-modules, supertest

I am trying to write API tests in typescript.

I've installed the following packages like this:

```
npm install -g mocha
npm install chai
npm install supertest
npm install supertest --save-dev
npm install supertest -g
npm install mocha@3.1.2 chai@3.5.0 chai-http@3.0.0 --save-dev
npm install @types/mocha@2.2.32 @types/chai@3.4.34 @types/chai-http@0.0.29 --save-dev
npm install ts-node@3.3.0 --save-dev
npm install typescript@2.0.6 --save-dev
```

I have typescript code that looks like this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as supertest from 'supertest';
import 'mocha';

var api = supertest('http://petstore.swagger.io');

describe('API test', () => {
  it('should return a 200 response from petstore', function (done) {
    api.get('/v2/store/inventory')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(200, done);
  });
})
```

However, when I try to run, I get this error:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/branches.ts  
C:\project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:307
        throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
              ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src\API\branches.ts (5,28): Cannot find module 'supertest'. (2307)
```

I don't understand why it cannot find supertest.  As you can see, I tried installing supertest in every way possible...  Also, I do have a folder in my 'node_modules' folder called 'supertest'.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3.0.0 and earlier of Supertest doesn't support ES6. There is an [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/215) about that on GitHub.

There is also a workaround posted there. I'll post it here in case the issue disappears:

**test_helper.js:**

```
import sinon from 'sinon'
import chai from 'chai'
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai'
var expect = chai.expect
chai.use(sinonChai)

var supertest = require("supertest");

module.exports = {
  sinon: sinon,
  chai: chai,
  expect: expect,
  supertest: supertest
}
```

**In your testing file:**

```
import {sinon, chai, expect, supertest} from '../test_helper'
```

Credit goes to [foxgaocn](https://github.com/foxgaocn).

Comment: Thanks! 

It worked after I changed my import command to:  "var supertest = require("supertest");"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after I had the same issue redeploying my node app to Heroku. Add this to your tsconfig.json

```
//This ensures your tests don't compile to js.
// But it means you must have `ts-jest` installed as a package so it can run 
//your test in typescript without need for compiling.
"exclude": ["path/to/your/tests/directory/*.test|spec.ts"]
```